# Icon on MacOS .command file (Terminal shell script) keeps disappearing

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, icon

I've created a `.command` file (a Terminal shell script) in MacOS, and with **Finder > Get Info**, I've given it a graphical icon, by dragging a `.png` file onto the icon object in the top left corner of Get Info.

However, the icon frequently disappears, and shows the default MacOS system icon for shell scripts. I then have to add the icon once more. Right now, I'm not sure exactly when the icon is disappearing, but it may be upon reboots or MacOS updates.

What may be the reason for the icon disappearing? Is this unexpected behavior (I don't seem to have this problem with other file icons on the system)? Is there a way of making its icon permanent? Should I use another method to achieve this, like creating an Automator app out of the command instead, in case MacOS happens to not like icons on `.command` files?

NB: The file itself contains a very simple Terminal command (like `open foo`), it doesn't contain a shebang or anything else.

Comment: is the image a `.icns` file?

Comment: Is the file in a folder that is 'synced' somewhere else, by any chance? Some syncing apps don't include extended attributes or ?Icon files, so they get stripped out.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -la@e theFile.command` and `xattr -l theFile.command` before and after it loses its icon?